# Consume function and send to cells

Tags: json, swift

how to do to receive the data and send put on cell ???

I'm following the model of a function that already exists and is returning but would like to have it in the cell

```
func getAllEstablishments(completion: @escaping (Result<[Establishment]>) -> Void) {
        var url = baseURL
        url.appendPathComponent("/api/establishment/list")

        let resultCompletion: (Result<[Establishment]>) -> Void = { result in
            do {
                let establishments = try result.unwrap()
               // completion(.success(value: nil))
                completion(.success(value: establishments))
                //completion(.success(value: nil))
                print("passou aqui get all")
            } catch {
                completion(.failure(error: error))
            }

        }

        request(url: url, isAuth: true, encoding: URLEncoding.default, completion: resultCompletion)
    }




 func fetchEstablishment(completion: ((Result<Void>) -> Void)? = nil) {
        app.networkManager.getAllEstablishments() { requestResult in

            do {
                let establishments = try requestResult.unwrap()

                try StorageHelper.store(establishments, to: StorageHelper.Directory.caches, as: "establishments.json")

                completion?(.success(value: ()))

            } catch let firstError {
                do {
                    _ = try StorageHelper.retrieve("establishments.json", from: StorageHelper.Directory.caches, as: [Establishment].self)
                    completion?(.success(value: ()))

                } catch {
                    completion?(.failure(error: firstError))

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm following the model of a function that already exists and is returning but would like to have it in the cell

Comment: I would like help to know how to consume this function and send it to a tableview

Comment: var establishments: Establishment? {
            return try? StorageHelper.retrieve("establishiments.json", from: StorageHelper.Directory.caches, as: Establishment.self)
  
            
        }